# Titanium Backup Pro - adb or shell command to switch profile

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

Tried searching everywhere for this, but seems I'm the only one who wants it (or can't figure it out!)

Is there a command to switch to another Titanium Backup Profile that can be executed from shell?

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers